# Spring - proper way to autowire GUI annotated with @Component in Main

Tags: java, spring, user-interface, spring-boot, autowired

I have my GUI class which is annotated with @Component like this:

```
@Component
public class AppGui {

@Autowired
private UserController userController;

private JPanel panel1;
private JButton button1;

public AppGui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
    frame.setContentPane(panel1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    button1.addActionListener(event -> {
        User user = new User(1, "bogdan", "password", true);
        String fileName = "file.xml";
        try {
            userController.save(user, fileName);
            userController.findOne(fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
}
```

And I have my main class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringMarshallApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //configurations
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class);
        context.refresh();
        new AppGui();
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMarshallApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Because GUI is annotated with `@Component` and I'm calling `new AppGui()` there are two user interfaces that are shown when I run the app.
What is the proper way of instantiating gui in my main using `Spring`?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

```
package com.example.controller;

import com.example.model.User;
import com.example.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by bogdan.puscasu on 4/19/2017.
 */
@Controller
public class UserControllerImpl implements UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void save(User user, String fileName) throws IOException {
        if (user != null) {
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getUsername()) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getPassword())) {
                userRepository.save(user,fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    public void findOne(String fileName) throws IOException {
        //todo: find by field
        userRepository.findOne(fileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :
To make Spring handle your AppGui class without declaring it manually in XML as a Spring bean, you need to

Annotate your class as a `@Component` like you did :

```
@Component
public class AppGui {
    [...]
}
```

And add the component scan directive in your Spring xml configuration file (and the spring context namespace if not already present) :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
        [...]
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    [...]
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
    [...]
</beans>
```

However to retrieve the bean from the spring context, you can call :

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
[...]
AppGui appGui = context.getBean(AppGui.class);
```

while the direct instantiation with the `new` keyword generates an object who's not handled by Spring.

Comment: Already tried this and : `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.gui.AppGui' available`

Comment: Have you you checked the entire error stacktrace? It' may be due to a previous problem with the autowiring of the UserController. Can you edit your post to add the definition of the `UserController` class ?

Comment: It's not because of the autowiring, I already checked that. Also posted the UserController class.

Comment: if your component is not handled by spring, may be the spring xml conf file misses the component-scan directive, i edited the response post with it.